# Google Apps - Send email from a nickname

Tags: email, google-apps

I have an email account in google apps 'user@mydomain.com' and it has a nickname 'nickname@mydomain.com'.

Can I send an email from 'nickname@mydomain.com'?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Definitely! Google Apps supports sending from any email address that you own, including nicknames.

1. Sign in to your Google Apps email.
2. Click Settings along the top of any
   page, and select the Accounts tab.
3. Under Send mail as, click Add another email address.
4. In the Email address field, enter your nickname.
5. Click Next Step >> and then click Send Verification. Gmail will send a verification message to your other email address to confirm that you own it.

The help center lists [more info](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=22370).

-- Eric