# Is it possible to send email from Google Apps from a Nickname in C#

Tags: c#, google-apps

I have a standard Google Apps account and they host my email for me..

Currently I can send emails in C# code, but they always come from my main email address..  I have a couple of nicknames setup... and in the Gmail interface, its possible as descibed here : [Google Apps - Send email from a nickname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587016/google-apps-send-email-from-a-nickname)

But I want to do this from code..  so I can send emails as "info@" or "support@"...
I have an appSetting called "EmailFrom" that is defined as "info@"...

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailFrom"], ToAddress);

//'(2) Assign the MailMessage's properties
mm.Subject = Subject;
mm.Body = MessageBody;
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

//'(3) Create the SmtpClient object
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

smtp.Port = System.Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPort"]);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;

smtp.Send(mm);
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok..

Figured it out...

It would seem that I needed to add the email address in the gmail interface...
Select the Settings menu, and choose Accounts....  then select "Add another email address you own"..
I just went through the verification process adding in the nickname I wanted to send from..

Easy..